# JSon output with Class name as root key value using JSon .NET

Tags: json.net

We are using Spring MVC as the back end in Java, where the entities are converted to Json with the class name as the root key value - for instance -

`{"MyPojo":{"id":4}}`
this is achieved in java / spring framework with the line - 
`objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);`

In JSON.NET do we have any properties which can make the class name be part of the json as the root key?

Answer (score -1):

sure, just make an anonymous object with a single property that is the name of your class like so:

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo { Bar = "baz" };
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {Foo = foo}).ToString(); //{"Foo":{"Bar":"asdf"}}
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```